# Why does my flex-wrap have large gaps and why does it change the flex-direction to a column?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

so when learning to use flex-box I noticed that my **flex-wrap:wrap** is positioned in a really weird way, depending on the viewpoint it have large gaps between the boxes.

Also for some reason the `flex-direction` is *column*:

[image: Extra spacing for some reason]

Also here's the code:

```css
.cont {
  display: flex;
  border: purple solid;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.cont div {
  padding: 10px;
  flex-basis: 300px;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, rgb(233, 47, 124), rgb(9, 175, 92));
}
```

```html
<div class="cont">
  <div class="box4">
    <h1>Box4</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box5">
    <h1>Box5</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box6">
    <h1>Box6</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box7">
    <h1>Box7</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box8">
    <h1>Box8</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box9">
    <h1>Box9</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box10">
    <h1>Box10</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The extra spacing happens for the second row because you have set `justify-content: space-between`. Here's an invaluable resource to flexbox: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: @pfcodes thanks for the resource fixed the misalignment but the abnormal amount of spacing is still there, I'll update the picture. Also do you know why flex-wrap changes the flex-direction to column?

Answer (score 1):

`flex-wrap` makes it so that the overflow of one row will *wrap* into a new row. The reason why it's overflowing so early leaving a big gap to the right is because the flex items are too wide to fit evenly into the container. Try decreasing the `flex-basis` value.

Comment: Actually I figured out the problem was because of the lack of the flex-grow property and your resource helped fix it. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by pfcodes, your items just don't fit in the row and therefore are wrapped.
Additionally, when you use `flex-wrap` you should consider the `align-content` property. You can think of it as the alignment for the cross axis when items wrap. In your case, as `flex direction` is `row` (the default), `align-content` will affect the vertical alignment of the wrapped lines. It takes the value `stretch` by default.

Take a look at [this](http://algid.com/Flex-Designer) helper tool for a better understanding and testing over `flexbox`.

Answer (score 0):

The `flex-wrap` property specifies whether the flexible items should wrap or not. In your case you have given `flex-basis:300px` and `padding:10px`, so each box width will be `flex-basis + padding-left + padding-right = 300+10+10 = 320px`(since you didn't set `box-sizing:border-box` padding will be included in width).

In your case the `div.cont` width is not enough for three boxes(`320*3=960px`) to sit there. So your box is wrapped onto next line. If you want to display three boxes in a row.

```
.cont div{
  padding:10px;
  flex-basis:calc(100% - 20px);
}
```

modified version of your code http://jsbin.com/luqevob/1/